# OpenVPN + unbound DNS: simultaneous usage possible on same machine?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, dns, openvpn

I am trying to run a OpenVPN tun server that listens to port 53 on UDP. I also am running unbound DNS on the same machine to provide DNS and filtering to the VPN and the machine itself.

I am unable to run both simultaneously (services will fail to start) due to port conflict, so is there a way to run both simultaneously that allows unbound to provide DNS service to the machine and VPN, as well as OpenVPN to also listen on port 53 UDP?

The machine runs Ubuntu 14.04, and the latest versions of OpenVPN and unbound.

Comment: Without using two diffrent IP Address, the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean that you changed the regular UDP listening port for OpenVPN, 1194, to 53? Why did you do that???

Ports below 1024 are best left alone because they generally are used for something important. None more port 53. Go back to using port 1194.

Otherwise, if you are really bent on using port 53 twice (are you behind a firewall you do not control?), place either service inside a VM, and make sure that the VM is not behind NAT, but has instead an IP address on your LAN.

If a VM too much of a hassle, you may try a lighter solution, a Linux Container (LXC) if you are on Linux. Ubuntu has some scripts that will do all of the work for you.

A new network-namespace will **not** do.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without two different ip addresses, is to use a different port for openvpn, since dns cannot operate over any other port, unless you're using a custom compiled dns server and client that uses a different port  (although I've never seen such a thing in real world usage although I'm sure it's possible).

Answer (score 0):

It **may** be possible, but it's a Really Bad Idea™. In order to accomplish this, you may very well have to do some C coding to patch this functionality into OpenVPN. Don't do this.

A common use case for tunnelling traffic over port 53, is to break out of captive portals. Is this what you want? Then you might want to look into [DNS tunnelling](http://code.kryo.se/iodine/%20%27%27iodine%20%28IP-over-DNS,%20IPv4%20over%20DNS%20tunnel%29%27%27).

Comment: I see that you successfully guessed what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use OpenVPN for this, if I understand what you're trying to do...  you probably want [Iodine](http://code.kryo.se/iodine/)